# I want to change default prefix of parquet files being created using Snowflake COPY INTO command with PARTITION BY option

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to change the default prefix (for instance *data_* to any desired text say *part-* ) of data files(.parquet) getting generated and uploaded to Azure blob using Snowflake COPY INTO command with PARTITION BY option. Tried the following way by putting desired prefix text( say *part-* ) at end of the file path, but a new folder is getting created instead of changing prefix of filenames.
Following is the sample COPY INTO command with PARTITION BY option that I have used:

```
    copy into 'azure://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/Sales/part-'
    from <schemaname>.<tablename>
    partition by ('SYS_ID=' || SYS_ID || '/YEAR=' || to_varchar(date_part(year, CREATED_ON)))    
    storage_integration = <integration name>
    file_format = (type=parquet)
```

New folder created with prefix text

[image]

Default prefix was not influenced

[image]

Expected filename with desired prefix instead of default one

[image]

Note: It works fine when I don't use PARTITION BY option but I have to use PARTITION BY option in order to have dynamic partition using Snowflake COPY INTO command.

is there a way to overcome the challenge?